# MySQL: Grant permissions for `start transaction` and "surroundings"

Tags: mysql, user-management

I have created a sample user with the following request:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on db.* to user@localhost identified by 'pass';
```

but that user does also need permission to use `start transaction` and `commit`. Which is the suitable permission to allow both commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't require a specific privilege, as a transaction just groups a number of database operations into one to maintain consistency. All you need is to have the privileges to do all operations within the transaction.

Please take the time to actually read the MySQL documentation.

Comment: The documentation is "too" huge, and I've searched on the Oracle docs, and, appart from receiving more articles in French and Japanese than in English, I have found nothing relating transactions and permission together. And altough I know a transaction is a package of operations, I didn't know if transaction operations are considered a sort of built-in procedures or something like that.